# .htaccess: Check for cookie, if none, 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cookies

Within .htaccess, is there a way to check for a cookie (doesn't even need to confirm the value, just the existence is fine)? If cookie: do nothing/load page.php; else 301 redirect.

```
Redirect 301 /page.php http://another-site.com
```

Here is where I'm at, stumbling a bit, work in progress.

```
RewriteRule ^page.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !cookie=123 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)  http://new-site.com [NC,L]
```

Comment: Sure, via mod_rewrite for example.

Comment: Thanks, working with that now, almost there I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !YourCookie=123 [NC]
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ http://new-site.com [R=301,L]
```

If your cookie (rename it as you want) does not contains `123` and url is `/page.php` then redirect to `http://new-site.com`

Comment: But it's not everything, it's just if a visitor is accessing page.php.

Comment: Sorry, i missed that point. I edited my answer, you can try again with the new code, should be good